# Python regex lookbehind swap groups

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I was practicing re module and encountered an interesting problem.

I can easily substitute two words:

```
re.sub("30 apples", r"apples 30", 'Look 30 apples.') # 'Look apples 30.'
```

But I want to swap the two words only if 30 comes before apples.

How to do this?

I tried look behind method:
`re.sub('(?<=\d\d) apples', r'\2 \1', 'Look 30 apples.')`

But it does not take groups \1 and \2.

Comment: `re.sub(r"(\d+)(\s+)(apples)", r"\3\2\1", 'Look 30 apples.')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  it solves the problem. Thanks. But I was looking if there exist any method using lookbehind, but may be lookbehind is much complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `(?<=\d\d) apples` pattern the match starts right after 2 digits and is a space plus `apples`. If you try to swap the two values, you need to *consume* both, and the lookbehind, as you see, does not consume text.

Thus, you need to use capturing groups here in the pattern and replace with the corresponding backreferences:

```
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)(\s+)(apples)", r"\3\2\1", 'Look 30 apples.')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhTYC5/1). [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5Cd%2B)(%5Cs%2B)(apples)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `(\s+)` - Capturing group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern): one or more whitespaces
- `(apples)` - Capturing group 3 (`\3` in the replacement pattern): `apples`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ugMBK1):

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)(\s+)(apples)", r"\3\2\1", "Look 30 apples.")
print(result)
```